# Foreign key assignment in Table per Type hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

[image]

Now if to the above diagram I had another table referring to some Instructor Specific Information. Then would the relationship in the database refer to the PersonID on the Instructor table or the Person table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will refer to the `PersonID` from the `Instructor` table.

It wouldn't make a sense if the other entity refers to the `Person` table, because not all entries in the `Person` table are instructors.